# ImageReader makes Camera lag

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm facing a problem where I am using a ImageReader in addition to have a SurfaceView which is used to show the output of the camera. I have added the SurfaceView itself and the surface for the ImageReader like this (and added the ImageReader listeners in order to receive events on new images):

```
preview.addTarget(_surfaces.get(1)); //ImageReader surface
preview.addTarget(_surfaces.get(0)); //SurfaceView of the layout
```

However, if I remove the ImageReader the application is working fine (no lagging from the camera). But as soon as the ImageReader surface is added the camera i lagging a lot. Anyone have any ideas in order to makes the camera run more smooth? The ImageReader is created like this:

```
reader = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
```

I guess the lag could be due to that the image has to be rendered two times(?), both on the SurfaceView of the layout and the ImageReader itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is the ImageFormat of the ImageReader. Changing the `ImageFormat.JPEG` to for example `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` fixed the lagging problem.

Comment: Surprisingly that did not worked for me. On not-so-high-end devices even `YUV_420_888` introduces some noticeable lag which was not the case with Camera v1.