# Android ImageReader motion detection

Tags: java, android, image-processing, image-formats, android-camera2

I'm developing an app which has to be able to do motion detection based on androids camera2 API. So i'm working with an ImageReader and the corresponding OnImageAvailableListener. I have two target surfaces for the Frames of the CameraCaptureSession, the UI SurfaceTexture where I show the preview of the camera, and the ImageReaders surface.

I was kind of "forced" to use ImageFormat.YUV_420_88 for the same reason as mentioned in this question:

[ImageReader makes Camera lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555545/imagereader-makes-camera-lag)

I'm kind of new to this Format and i need to implement a motion detection.

My idea is to loop through Image.getPlanes()[i].getBuffer() pixel-wise and compare two images based on a certain threshold.

I have two Questions:

1. Is this a good idea? Is there maybe a better / more efficient way?
2. Which of the Plane(s) from the Format YUV_420_88 is best suited for such motion detection?

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Is this a good idea? Is there maybe a better / more efficient way?

Yes, it is. 
There is no other way then compare continued frames to detect motion event.

> 2. Which of the Plane(s) from the Format YUV_420_88 is best suited for such motion detection?

I think it is Planes()[0].

My sample code:

```
mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
            Image image = null;
            try {
                image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
                if (null == image) {
                    return;
                }
                ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                buffer.get(bytes);

                detectMotion(bytes);
            } finally {
                if (image != null) {
                    image.close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void detectMotion(byte[] frame) {
            if (null == frame) {
                return;
            }

            int ret = NativeUtil.detectMotion(frame);
            if (ret == 1) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mIvMotion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                Log.d(TAG, "Detected motion event");
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mIvMotion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Where is NativeUtil.detectMotion?